# Header function with increasing number in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to have a function in bash that I can use in some install scripts to announce that the next paragraph is starting.

A simple solution (with colors) would be

```
headline(){
  echo -e "\e[1;34m###########################################"
  echo -e "##########  \e[1;37m$*"
  echo -e "\e[1;34m###########################################\e[0m"
}
```

But How do I add an increasing number in it?

Comment: You want me to modify my answer to do colors?

Answer (score 3):

This is what you want, right?

```
#!/bin/bash
function headline(){
  echo -e "\e[1;34m###########################################"
  echo -e "#####  Starting paragraph: $1.$2  #####\e[1;37m"
  echo -e "\e[1;34m###########################################\e[0m"
  number=$(($1 + 1))
}
number=1
headline $number "hello"
sleep 1
headline $number "hi everybody"
sleep 1
headline $number "goodnight"

#OUTPUT:
###########################################
#####  Starting paragraph: 1.hello  #####
###########################################
###########################################
#####  Starting paragraph: 2.hi everybody  #####
###########################################
###########################################
#####  Starting paragraph: 3.goodnight  #####
###########################################
```

Comment: nearly. How do I add a title then to each paragraph? can't I call it without the number argument? so it automatically counts internally inside the function?

Comment: Hm, I do not quite understand what you want. Could you please give an example?

Comment: This looks better, but do I really have to add `$number` on each call? can't it be solved internal in that function? (And I think the `#####` at the end looks untidy, if it is not the same length like the lines around)

Comment: Hey, you can certainly combine mikeserv's response letting bash determine the proper number/length of letters to decide on the number/length of hashes. And yes, you can certainly include the $number calculation/print internaly without passing it as an argument every time. Try it and let us know if you have any problems. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html will be very helpful and I guess we would like to see the final version of the script.

Comment: The problem with this answer is not the argument - that's the good part - the problem is you get only one increment per shell. The increment is always `$number` - both inside and outside the function - which means it might as well not be a function and could just as easily be a `for` loop. There is no indirection. In order to indirectly reference the name of the command-line argument you have to pass the function just the name - with no `$`expansion and let the arithmetic evaluation do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

If there is anything the shell is very good at it is mangling arguments. And this is as it should be - the shell's primary purpose is to interpret and pass those arguments along.

What follows is composed *almost* entirely of shell builtins - excepting `tr` and *possibly* `printf` - and is *very nearly* POSIX portable code with the one exception being my use of `local` which is not a POSIX specified utility but which is pretty much ubiquitous. To emulate `local` we might do one more one-line function but I doubt if it's necessary.

#### TWO SHELL FUNCTIONS:

```
#let printf handle the printing
_hashes() { printf %0$((${1}))d\\n | tr 0 \# ; }

_hdr_inc() { local _hinc=${1##*-} _hashc=${2##*[!0-9]}
    : ${_hinc:=$(set -- $3 ; printf %s_cnt\\n "${1-_hdr}")}
    ${1+shift} ${2+2}
    _hashes ${_hashc:=40}
    printf "%s #$((${_hinc}=${_hinc}+1)):${1+%b}" \
        ${1+"$*"} ${1+\\c}Default
    echo && _hashes $_hashc
}
```

Both functions will accept any number of command-line arguments gracefully *(within $ARGMAX limits)*.

```
_hashes
```

..for example, will print you only a single `#`hash then a `\n`ewline. But adding any arguments after the first is futile - `_hashes()` will ignore them.

```
_hdr_inc - - and a bunch of extras
```

...on the other hand will at once either increment by one from its current value or from zero a shell variable named `$and_cnt` and print to its `stdout` the 3 line string result of doing approximately:

```
_hashes 40
echo and a bunch of extras \#$((and_cnt=and_cnt+1)):
_hashes 40
```

Just ...

```
_hdr_inc
```

... does similar, but with all default values:

```
_hashes 40
echo Default \#$((_hdr_cnt=_hdr_cnt+1)):
_hashes 40
```

But setting explicit values for all args:

```
_hdr_inc counter 31 Some string
```

...does...

```
_hashes 31
echo Some string \#$((counter=counter+1)):
_hashes 31
```

Or just the first:

```
_hdr_inc counter
```

...does...

```
_hashes 40
echo Default \#$((counter=counter+1))
_hashes 40
```

#### DEMO

```
(   set -- Header Paragraph
    for h do {
        _hdr_inc ; echo
        _hdr_inc - - $h ; echo
        _hdr_inc - 20 $h And More\! ; echo
        _hdr_inc - 30 ; echo
        _hdr_inc $h - ; echo
    } ; done
    set -- $1 $1 $1 $1 $2 $2 $2 $2
    printf 'echo "Custom increment \\$%s_cnt = $%s_cnt"
        echo "Explicit increment \\$%s = $%s"\n' "$@" |
        . /dev/stdin
    echo 'Default increment $_hdr_cnt =' $_hdr_cnt
)
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
########################################
Default #1:
########################################

########################################
Header #1:
########################################

####################
Header And More! #2:
####################

##############################
Default #2:
##############################

########################################
Default #1:
########################################

########################################
Default #3:
########################################

########################################
Paragraph #1:
########################################

####################
Paragraph And More! #2:
####################

##############################
Default #4:
##############################

########################################
Default #1:
########################################

Custom increment $Header_cnt = 2
Explicit increment $Header = 1
Custom increment $Paragraph_cnt = 2
Explicit increment $Paragraph = 1
Default increment $_hdr_cnt = 4
```

Comment: This only writes the number but not the title. How do I add a different title to each paragraph?

Comment: @rubo77 - true. That's fixed now - and a little more.