# What does ${3#?} do?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have a script with the following variable assignment:

```bash
TEST_VARIABLE=${3#?}
```

What does the `${3#?}` do?

Answer (score 6):

That is called parameter expansion:

1. `$3` is your variable, which is the third parameter of the script/function.
2. `#` will remove the shortest prefix of the variable.
3. `?` is the pattern you are looking for (in this case is any character).

So basically you remove the shortest prefix of the variable named `3` until you find the pattern.

In general, we can consider:

```
${variable_name[option][pattern]}
```

There are other options like:

- `##` remove largest prefix.
- `%` remove shortest suffix.
- `%%` remove largest suffix.

Which you can combine with other patterns, for example, for getting the last field of a CSV line:

```
> string="asdf,1234,aa,foo22"
> echo ${string##*,}
foo22
```

Notice how we have removed the largest prefix searching for the pattern "any character(s) followed by a comma".

Answer (score 3):

```
> set -- 1 2 foo
> echo "$3"
foo
TEST_VARIABLE=${3#?}
> echo "$TEST_VARIABLE"
oo
```

It assigns the value of the third positional parameter without its first char to the variable `TEST_VARIABLE` (the positional parameter itself is not changed); used in functions or shell scripts:

```
./myscript 1 2 foo
# or
myfunc 1 2 foo
  # within each $3 is foo
```

In order to have positional parameters within an interactive shell you need `set`.

Comment: Why do you write "usually used in functions"? I'm at a loss to understand why you'd want to drop the first character of an argument.

Comment: @BruceEdiger That was bad wording indeed. I meant "You don't have that in interactive shells" but, of course, it's pretty normal in scripts, too. And I have no idea either why someone should use this code.

Comment: @BruceEdiger - could be just a sloppy means of removing a leading `-dash`? Still, it's impossible to judge without the code. By the way, though, it doesn't actually drop the first character of the positional parameter - it expands without it. So `set -- one two three ; echo "${3#?}" "$3"` gets you `hree` and `three`. You don't lose anything - it's still there. You'd have to `set --` to clear the args.

Comment: @BruceEdiger - I wrote this other answer today about argument mangling and it reminded me of your comment about dropping a character from an argument. I do *at least* that several times over in this little function and I feel it's justified. Am I crazy? http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132447/52934

Comment: @mikeserv - your code doesn't look crazy to me. If you need to remove the first character of a variable's value, that's one way of doing it.  The "${3#?}" usage seems to hide what it's doing, rather than make it explicit.

Comment: @BruceEdiger - true - it was more the use of `?` that made me refer to it as *sloppy*. If youve already got the one unknown in `$[0-9]*` adding the second `?` cant help much. But probably thats why they called it `$TESTVARIABLE` - they probably checked what came off if they removed only the first character like `${3%$TESTVARIABLE}`. A simpler way to do the same is just `${3%"${3#?}"}` or - and perhaps easier to review - `printf %c "$3"`. Or maybe they were just sloppy. I dunno.